# Java: update statuses concurrently

Tags: java, database, multithreading

- I have many tasks, which have statuses. Statuses are persisted to a database. At the moment I persist all statuses in a single thread:

  ```
  executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  ...
  executor.submit(new UpdateStatusTask(taskId, status));
  ```

  which is safe, but kills concurrency.
- On the other hand, if I add more threads, it might result in a corrupted data -- later task status may become overwritten by an ealier one.
- I see a solution in executing *status updates* in parallel, but in such a way, that status updates for one task is always executed on a single thread. If *runnables* are put in a queue, it'll guarantee consistency (later status updates are executed after earlier status updates).

Are there any standart/Apache/Guava etc. utility class to perform such a task?

Comment: Why not using database-managed locks for that?

Comment: How are you persisting things into your database? Databases are good at concurrency, and as @VitalijZadneprovskij writes, many can achieve concurrent writes (as long as the rows are different); and will use locking to prevent synchronization issues without you having to do anything.

Comment: Why not use Actors? (Akka): one Actor per Task. Actors always execute on the same thread and provide ordered message queuing

Answer (score 1):

You should update status of the same task by the same thread.

```
public class TaskStatusUpdater {

    private final int threadCount;
    private final ExecutorService[] executors;

    public TaskStatusUpdater(int threadCount) {
         this.threadCount = threadCount;
         executors = new ExecutorService[threadCount];
         for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
             executors[0] = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
         }
    }

    public void submitTask(int taskId, Runnable task) {
         int index = Integer.hashCode(taskId) % threadCount;
         executors[index].submit(task);
     }
 }
```

Comment: That'll work! Just was wondering, if there is more elegant solution out there.